# Reatcjs accessing obejct properties in an array and in nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I have here is react component PokemonInfo where I want to return in this case the `stats.base_stat` from `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/` json. the problem is that `base_stat` is inside an array `stats`. I assume that it can be done with somehow mapping the `stats` array, but how?

This is what I came up to, but nothing seems to work.

**App**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import PokemonList from "./PokemonList";
import PokemonInfo from "./PokemonInfo";
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pokemon: {},
      pokemons: [],
    };
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          pokemons: response.results
        });
      });
  }
  handleOnClick(pokeurl) {
    fetch(pokeurl)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
      **// console.log("this is the `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/` JSON", data);**
        //const infopokemon = new Pokemon(data);
        this.setState({ pokemon: data });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  render() {
   // if(this.state.pokemon)
       //console.log("eto dannije kotorije nado vitashitj iz massiva", 
this.state.pokemon.weight);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PokemonList pokemons={this.state.pokemons} handleClick= 
          {(url)=>this.handleOnClick(url)} />
        <PokemonInfo pokemon={this.state.pokemon}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

What would be the correct way to return this value? Where exactly and how to use map() methodin this case?

**Updated PokemonInfo**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './pokemon-info.css';
const PokemonInfo = ({ pokemon }) => {
  const { 
    name, 
          height, 
          weight, 
          sprites,
        } = pokemon;
const {sprites: {front_default}} = pokemon;
  return (
    <section className="pokemonInfo">
      <img src={front_default} className='sprite-image' 
alt="pokemon_sprite"/>
      <div className='data-wrapper'>
        <h3 className="data-char"><strong>{name}</strong></h3><br />
        <p className = 'data-char'>Height: {height}</p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Weight: {weight}</p><br />
        <p className = 'data-char'>Stats: </p><br />
        {pokemon.stats.map((statInfo, i) => {
          return <p className='data-char' key=
            {i}>{statInfo.stat.name}: {statInfo.base_stat}</p>
        })} 
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
export default PokemonInfo;
```

Comment: So to clarify, you want to select a pokemon from the PokemonList and display its info in PokemonInfo?

Comment: That is correct. I've already managed to display pokemons name, weight and height, but that's because these props are not inside of the pokemon object nested array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just a syntax error. in PokemonInfo, change this:

```
{this.props.pokemon.stats.map(speed => {
      return <p className='data-char' speed={speed} key= 
              {speed.stat.name}>Speed: {stats.base_stat}</p>})}
```

to this:

```
{pokemon.stats.map(statInfo => {
          return <p className='data-char' key=
            {statInfo.stat.name}>{statInfo.stat.name}: {statInfo.base_stat}</p>
        })}
```

Notes: don't use `this` inside functional components. If you need access to the rest of the props without losing your destructuring you can use the rest operator:

```
const PokemonInfo = ({ pokemon }, ...props) => {
  // use as props.otherProp
}
```

**EDIT**

To avoid TypeErrors I suggest initializing your `pokemon` object with the correct keys instead of an empty object. In App, your initial state should look like this:

```
state = {
  pokemons: [],
  pokemon: {
   name: "", 
   height: "", 
   weight: "",
   stats: [], 
   sprites: {
     front_default: "",
     //other keys you might need
   },
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. look like it treats `map` method like a property?

Comment: That's because the initial value of `pokemon` is `{}`, either initialize the object with the right key or validate that the key is present and is an array before mapping

Comment: Thank You for the answer, it did help me a lot. I have added `stats[]` to the initial state of `pokemon` and it works! Now I just have to find out how to get the sprite, which is supposed to be in `{sprites.front_default}`, but I see this in my console `TypeError: Cannot read property 'front_default' of undefined`. I have updated my question where I try to destructure nested object, but that does not seem to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

As `PokemonInfo` is declared as a functional component `this.props` won't work. And you have already done the [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of the passed prop `pokemon` to a const variable, you can directly do `.map` iteration of `stats` array object as shown in the below code.

And as we are iterating over the `stats` array, you can access `base_stat` props from your iteratee, which is 'speed' in your case. so replace `stats.base_stat` with `speed.base_stat`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './pokemon-info.css';
const PokemonInfo = ({ pokemon }) => {
  const { name, 
          height, 
          weight, 
          stats,
        } = pokemon;
  return (
    <section className="pokemonInfo">
      <img className='sprite-image' alt="pokemon_sprite"/>
      <div className='data-wrapper'>
        <h3 className="data-char">{name}</h3><br />
        <p className = 'data-char'>Height: {height}</p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Weight: {weight}</p><br />
        <p className = 'data-char'>Stats: </p><br />
        {stats.map(speed => {
          return <p className='data-char' speed={speed} key= 
                  {speed.stat.name}>Speed: {speed.base_stat}</p>})}

        <p className = 'data-char'>Special defense: </p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Special attack: </p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Defense: </p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Attack: </p>
        <p className = 'data-char'>Hp: </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
export default PokemonInfo;
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer! It worked out with @SrThompson option